# Associate Multidimensional array in html

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have two fields

url and id

```
<input type='url' name='data[web][url]'><input type='number' name='data[web][id]'>
<input type='url' name='data[web][url]'><input type='number' name='data[web][id]'>
<input type='url' name='data[web][url]'><input type='number' name='data[web][id]'>
```

Now when I give the input and submit the form I want the output be like.

```
Array(
  [0]=>[
      [data] =>[
        'url' =>url1,
        'id'  =>id1
       ],
    ],
  [1]=>[
      [data] =>[
        'url' =>url2,
        'id'  =>id2
       ],
    ],
  [2]=>[
      [data] =>[
        'url' =>url3,
        'id'  =>id3
       ],
    ],

)
```

Is it possible to associate the inputs like the above example?

Comment: Aren't you able to change html name a bit? A small change and nothting to do with php. Isn't it possible? If yes then you can take help from my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want (can't) change your HTML markup (regarding PHP tag), in PHP it could be something like

```
<?php

# data from your form
$data = array(
    'web' => array(
        'url' => array(
            'url1',
            'url2',
            'url3'
        ),

        'id' => array(
            'id1',
            'id2',
            'id3'
        )
    )
);


$output = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['web']['url']); $i++) {
    $output[$i]['data']['url'] = $data['web']['url'][$i];
    $output[$i]['data']['id'] = $data['web']['id'][$i];
}

echo '<PRE>';
print_r($output);
```

Output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [url] => url1
                    [id] => id1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [url] => url2
                    [id] => id2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [url] => url3
                    [id] => id3
                )

        )

)
```

I've used `$data` variable, you will have `$_POST['data']` there instead.